# How to use regex or replace to clean up list?

Tags: python, regex, replace

This seems like a very obvious mistake which I have been trying to solve for almost an hour now. :(

```
lst = ['\xa0\xa0+11-9188882266\xa0\xa0+01-9736475634 ','\xa0\xa0+11-9177772266\xa0\xa0+01-9736475234']
```

I am trying to grab numbers, hyphens and the + sign only. Basically remove all the `\xa0`.

I thought that `Regex` would be the right way to go about it. Tried it and failed:

```
mRegex = (['+0-9-'])
lst = re.match(mRegex,lst)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 160, in match
>      return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 282, in _compile
>      p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
>   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I gave it a few more tries with `regex` then switched to `replace`:

`h.replace(r"\xa0","")`

It doesn't do anything to the `lst`. Stays exactly the same.

When I do a `len(lst[0])` I get `33` which is very odd.

In a:

```
for i in lst[0]:
    print(i)
```

the output doesn't show `\xa0`.

I am completely confused here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first, you cannot apply replacement/regex on a list. You have to apply them for each string, and use a list comprehension to rebuild the cleaned-up list.

second, when you replace you're using the *raw* prefix, when you shouldn't use it, since it treats `\x` literally, not that you want.

I'd do:

```
lst = [x.replace("\xa0","") for x in lst]
```

results in:

```
['+11-9188882266+01-9736475634 ', '+11-9177772266+01-9736475234']
```

and BTW: `mRegex = (['+0-9-'])` doesn't work because you're basically defining a list of 1 string. You probably meant `mRegex = '([0-9\-+])'`

A regex solution would be:

```
lst = [re.sub(r"[^\d+\-]","",x) for x in lst]
```

(removes chars not matching the char class, and `\d` is (roughly) equivalent to `0-9`)

After a few years I realize (after reading OP comment properly this time) that the expected result is probably the numbers separated in a list, so removing `\xa0` isn't a good idea, because it collates the numbers. Let's just use `split` on each string:

```
>>> lst = ['\xa0\xa0+11-9188882266\xa0\xa0+01-9736475634 ','\xa0\xa0+11-9177772266\xa0\xa0+01-9736475234']
>>> [x.split() for x in lst]
[['+11-9188882266', '+01-9736475634'], ['+11-9177772266', '+01-9736475234']]
```

Actually using `split()` works because `\xa0` is seen as a space character (windows uses it for instance), and also removes multiple instances of spaces, so the result is given straight away without further hassle.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works perfectly. However, in the meantime I tried: `h=lst[0]` `h.split()` and for some reason now I am only getting the number as two separate list items. exactly what I wanted but it would be great if an explanation of it is possible.

Comment: that's because `\xa0` is some kind of whitespace (0x20 + 0x80 = 0xa0) used in windows console. `split` detects it and splits the numbers according to the whitespace.